# Reading excel but values are coming in different format

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, excel

I am making another windows form application , but some weird things are happening , first example i have a value 0076464688334 , in my excel sheet i am reading them using..

```
        MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + fileName + "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
        MyConnection.Open();
        myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        String qry = "SELECT number FROM [Sheet1$]";
        OleDbDataAdapter odp = new OleDbDataAdapter(qry, MyConnection);
        odp.Fill(ds);
```

NO when i have all the values in dataset i loop them n do some thing , but the problem is the value i mentioned above all all those who have zero at front become like .

```
         0076464688334  = 76464688334
```

I kind on replaces 0 with %0 and in code %0 with 0 and it solved , now another problem is that i have a value it is becoming...

```
         824968717929  = 8.2496871793e+011
```

These are bar codes and i need exact match , can not find how to solve them , help please :).

Thank you in advance to all..

Additional code:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() != "" )
                {
                    googleList.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString().Replace("%0", "0"));


                 //   EbayList.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());

                    string tmp = string.Empty;
                    tmp = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString().Replace("%0","0");
```

Comment: I also faced this problem give me moment i give you solution how to get data from excel properly.

Comment: Thank you, looking forward to it :)

Comment: I posted answer two links in it first one giving full information and other link is my customize code with dll. Check it too.

Comment: sorry but i was finding it too hard to understand.

Comment: Just add reference in your application, convert code in c# and pass the excel file path to it, It will in return give you excel file data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the type of the cell in excel because the values in the cell are transformed to simple numbers.

To do that you can set the Format to text, which will then be mapped to a string with your reader.

Alternatively you can use the COM interfaces to read your spreadsheets or try this one:

[ExcelDataReader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/)

if they are in open office format (.XLSX files) you can use

[EPP Plus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/67324)

Comment: Thank you, very nice and easy to understand  :).

Comment: Try the Text type in Excel. Should work. If you happy with this you can up vote ;)